# Enable zooming and panning in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a problem with my leaflet map, whenever I zoom in/out or drag the map it bounces back to the original state. How do I disable this effect?

Comment: Please add information about your leaflet version as well as which client system (browser) for which this is an issue.

Comment: you also need to add some code to show the effect

Comment: I would add the code. It sounds like you have limited the extents of the map so much that no panning is possible.